# How to prompt facebook login with jQuery-Facebook-Photo-Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to modify this jQuery plugin for a FB Photo Selector so that you don't have to click "Login with Facebook" before opening up the FB Photo Selector by clicking "Select from your photos".

The flow that I am looking for is that you click on "Select from your photos" and if you are authenticated with FB to this app, then it will prompt you to provide your Facebook credentials with the typical FB dialog. After log-in, it should open the photo selector modal.

If you have already logged in with facebook, then it will continue to the photo selector modal.

Here is the github for the plugin:
https://github.com/cshold/jQuery-Facebook-Photo-Selector

This is a live demo:
http://labs.carsonshold.com/fb-photo-selector/

This is the relevant code from csphotoselector.js

```
        // Check that the user is logged in to Facebook
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            // Load Facebook photos
            FB.api('/'+ id +'/albums', function(response) {
                if (response.data.length) {
                    setAlbums(response.data);
                    // Build the markup
                    buildMarkup(accessToken);
                    // Call the callback
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback(); }
                } else {
                    alert ('Sorry, your friend won\'t let us look through their photos');
                    log('CSPhotoSelector - buildAlbumSelector - No albums returned');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            log('CSPhotoSelector - buildAlbumSelector - User is not logged in to Facebook');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

hello when our team use this code we face problem like "Sorry, your friend won\'t let us look through their photos" when another user login via fb and show only for user which user create appliocation.

Comment: @FernandoAureliano we solve this problem by create new application on facebook.we provided all detail regarding my application then when facebook approv my application for this service of proved user photo. we able to access this services